# Finding and Removing Object From Array with Specified Date Key

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JavaScript array of objects that has ISO 8601 date strings as keys, and a number for the value like this:

```
var myArray = [
  {"Wed May 27 2015 04:46:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)":1.1},
  {"Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)":2.2}
]
```

I want to find and remove any objects that match a certain date like this:

```
var myDate = "Wed May 27 2015 04:46:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

if(myDate is a key in myArray){
  //Remove it from myArray
}
```

And the result would be that `myArray` now looks like this:

```
[{"Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)":2.2}]
```

I have Underscore JS available, but I can't figure this out.

Comment: Dates aren't ISO 8601 strings in your code snippets.

Comment: Hmm... are they the wrong format? I'm using Parse, and this is the format it returns and they claim their `Date` data type is ISO 8601.

Comment: ISO 8601 Universal datetime template: YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ. `new Date().toJSON()` returns current date/time in ISO 8601. But `new Date().toString()` returns current date/time in human format like in your code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [`_.has`](http://underscorejs.org/#has), [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) and [`_.negate`](http://underscorejs.org/#negate) methods, like this

```
console.log(_.filter(myArray, _.partial(_.negate(_.has), _, myDate)));
// [ { 'Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)': 2.2 } ]
```

- Here, `_.negate(_.has)` will return a new function which will just negate the result of `_.has` always.
- `_.partial(_.negate(_.has), _, myDate)` will return a new function which will accept the values from `myArray` in the placeholder `_` and `_.has` will be invoked with the value from the `myArray` and `myDate` as arguments.
- `_.has` will return `true` if the object passed as the first argument has a key with the same name as the second parameter passed to it.

---

**For older version of _**

If you are using an older version of `_`, then you can simply pass a function object to do this,

```
console.log(_.filter(myArray, function(currentObject) {
    return !_.has(currentObject, myDate);
}));
// [ { 'Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)': 2.2 } ]
```

---

**Vanila JS Version**

```
console.log(myArray.filter(function(currenObject) {
    return !currenObject.hasOwnProperty(myDate);
}));
// [ { 'Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)': 2.2 } ]
```

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function and check if the current object has a property with the value of `myDate`, with [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

If you are sure that the `myDate` will not have a value which will not be one of the inherited properties of Object, then you can also use [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), like this

```
console.log(myArray.filter(function(currenObject) {
    return !(myDate in currenObject);
}));
// [ { 'Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)': 2.2 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) I had to use the `filter` version since I have an older version of Underscore. The only catch is that your solution is returning the value matching `myDate` instead of *removing* that value from the array.

Comment: You can assign the result to `myArray`. The advantage here is we don't mutate the original object

Comment: I've done that, but again, it's having the opposite effect. It's returning an array with `myDate` in it instead of an array *without* `myDate` in it.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Okay, I updated the original _ version with `_.negate` and other versions with the native logical not operator (`!`). Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the underscoreJs, but I hope this simple way will help you out.

```
var myArray = [
              {"Wed May 27 2015 04:46:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)":1.1},
              {"Wed May 24 2015 10:34:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)":2.2}
            ];
var myDate = "Wed May 27 2015 04:46:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)";

for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
{
    if(myDate == Object.keys(myArray[i]))
    {
        myArray.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```